# Infinite objects declaration in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script in Unity that holds checkpoints in my racing game. But I don't know exactly how many checkpoints are on racetracks. Now I am limited to 5:

[image]

but, I would like to allow map makers to insert more checkpoints.
This doesn't work:

```
public List<GameObject> checkPoints = new List<GameObject>();
```

so what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? How exactly would you like the map makers to add new checkpoints?

Comment: i want to make something like vector. Map makers will add checkpoints to this script if they add one to the scene

Comment: why does the list doesn't work. could you explain a bit more?

Comment: when i use this code, list don't appears in this window (like on the screen). I want to create script that can store all of the checkpoints on the map.

Comment: post the whole code of your script. A public list of GameObject will be show correctly in the inspector .

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't defining an array of checkpoints work?

`public GameObject[] CheckPoints;`

I don't have access to Unity at the moment, but that should allow you to enter any (reasonable) number of GameObjects via the inspector to the CheckPoints array.

This on the Unity Answers is similar to this question: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/245024/public-array-of-gameobjects.html

Taking a wild guess here, is your error `List1' could not be found`? In which case you'll have to add `using System.Collections.Generic;` to be able to use the C# Lists.

Comment: this is fine but a List<GameObject> works too. Probably the OP's error is somewhere else.

Comment: @Heisenbug I thought it was, but I'm not able to test it at the moment. I suppose the reason his List isn't working is because he's creating it script side? (`public List<GameObject> foo = new List<GameObject>();` as opposed to just public `List<GameObject> foo;` though "This doens't work" doesn't really describe his problem, you're right, it's probably somewhere else.

Comment: No. Even if he initialize it inside the script, it should be inspectable too. Btw initializing it both inside the script and via editor could eventually cause some other bugs.

Comment: @Heisenbug Any examples of those types of bugs?  I've always found it harmless (though useless) to initialize public members.  As far as I've ever seen Unity's Editor serialization process is pretty good at handling this type of thing.

Comment: @Jerdak: if you initialize an array from the inspector, unity will correctly serialize them. If you initialize it again (es. inside Awake) the array initialized in the inspector would be lost.

Comment: @Heisenbug Ok I see what you're saying, yeah that's always something to watch for.

Answer (score -2):

This: `public List<GameObject> checkPoints = new List<GameObject>();` doesn't show up because it's a list of GameObjects, not a list of Vectors. Users can't manually type in GameObjects. You could do: `public List<Vector3> checkPoints = new List<Vector3>();` and then simply iterate through this list and do a Resource.Load for each position at runtime (if you can't figure this out, I could type up an example).

A more user friendly solution would be to allow users to add  checkpoints by placing a GameObject in the world, rather than having to type each vector manually. So for instance, create a CheckPoint object, and give it a unique tag (eg: "CheckPointTag"), then simply run the method bellow to get all the checkpoint positions:

```
public List<Vector3> GetCheckPoints()
{
     GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("CheckPointTag");
     List<Vector3> objectPos = new List<Vector3>();
     foreach(GameObject object in objects)
          objectPos.Add(object.transform.Position;

     return objectPos;
}
```

Comment: Had to downvote because it makes a misleading point. Users cannot directly type in a GameObject, no, but that has no relevance, they can drag-drop either an instance of a GameObject, or a prefab to be instantiated, to a GameObject property via the inspector.

Comment: You can, but maybe I just didn't phrase my answer right. I didn't mean he can't add GameObjects to a list this way, just that he can't type them in, which seemed to be what he was after when he said this: **i want to make something like vector. Map makers will add checkpoints to this script if they add one to the scene**